# Calculate $a,b$ for a probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I'm learning probability and trying to solve the following problem:

> Determine $a,b$ so that probability density function will be:
> $\left\{\begin{matrix} x & x \in (0,1)  \\  a+bx & x \in [1,2] \\  0 &
> > else  \end{matrix}\right. $.

However, I'm stuck at one step.

Here is my attempt so far:

$\int_{0}^{1} x dx = \frac{1}{2}$ --> not a probability density function

$\int_{1}^{2} a+bx dx = a+b\frac{3}{2}$

$a+b\frac{3}{2}=1$ --> stuck here. I'm not sure how to solve it and find values so that it would equal $1$.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want that $a+3b/2=1$? If anything, you'd want it to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I thought that is has to be $1$, because it's a PDF. Could you please explain?

Comment: It must be $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx +\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx = 1.$ Since  $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx =1/2$ you need to check $\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx = 1/2.$

Comment: @mfl Oh, okay, I get it now. But still, how should I solve $a+b\frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$? This is the part I didn't know even before.

Comment: you looks like you need to assume continuity of the pdf at $x=1$  so $a+b=1$. Some evidence  that you need to do this is that this does end up making the pdf continuous at $x=2$ also

Comment: This makes it a poorly posed question because, in general, continuity is not a requirement for a pdf